# Password Reset for old PC

Tags: 14.04

So, I just bought a laptop with Ubuntu on it at a pawnshop and I can't do anything since the person sold it had not written down his password or recovery key, did I waste my money or is there a way to fix this? Please help.

Comment: I would recommend that you install a fresh Ubuntu on it, alone for your own data security.

Comment: I would also strongly recommend you to do a fresh install. I would not bother with a used and possibly messed up system. Ubuntu is free and there are no license keys required, so simply download a fresh Ubuntu iso and do a clean reinstall. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Boot from Ubuntu Live CD.

Open terminal, type `sudo fdisk -l`

Find your Ubuntu partition (by comparing size or other numbers in file manager).

Mount it on /mnt by `sudo mount /dev/sdxy` where x should be letter (a, b, c, etc.) and y should be a number.

Chroot into it by `sudo chroot /mnt`

Run `passwd` and change password for root or `passwd user` for other users.